# Indent RTF Text in RichTextBox without losing the RTF style

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, rtf, auto-indent

I'd want to indent RTF text in a RichTextBox without losing the RTF style.

```
Dim Alinea As String = "    "

Private Sub Indent_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Indent.Click
    Try
        Dim Output As String = Nothing
        Dim Split() As String = RichTextBox1.Lines
        For i = 0 To Split.Length - 1
            Output = String.Concat(Output, Split(i).Insert(0, Alinea), If(Not i = Split.Length - 1, vbNewLine, Nothing))
        Next
        RichTextBox1.Text = Output
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The previous code works, but it returns the text without any style.

I'd just like to add `Alinea` on all beginnings of line of the RichTextBox text.
I've tried to use the `RichTextBox1.Rtf` property, but it shows a MsgBox saying "File format not valid".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using RichTextBox1.Lines, use RichTextBox1.Rtf.

```
RichTextBox1.Rtf = RichTextBox1.Rtf.Replace(vbCrLf, vbCrLf & vbTab)
```

This works, but you may want to key on something like `\par` or `\par & vbcrlf` to adhere more to the rtf standard.

```
RichTextBox1.Rtf = RichTextBox1.Rtf.Replace("\par" & vbCrLf, "\par" & vbCrLf & vbTab)
```

"It is left as an exercise to the reader" to make it work on the first line and for any whitespace character following "\par". (I always hated that phrase.)

Comment: The problem, using Replace vbCrLf is that it doesn't work for the first line... Is there another way with a loop, as I did before ?

Comment: You can do it with a loop, however there's not a property that provides separate lines of the rich text. You would need to do that before the loop with the string split function, or something similar.